# How to show minus and plus sign in regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I wrote a code that can take some values from the internet, and it works quite well.
The only drawback is that the operators **+** and **-** are not shown in my table.
If for example I have a value type: +8 or -9
the regex me back 8 and 9, while I wish that the variable is mantained the + and - in front of the respective figures, such as +8 and -9..
The course is variable of type string as I do?

```
 .Differenza_reti = Val(Regex.Match(Content, "<td class=""number gd""\s*>[\+\-]?(\d+)</td>").Groups(1).ToString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the character class inside of the capturing group to retain them.

```
([+-]?\d+)
```